# Auth middleware not redirecting to login page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I have this situation where I have a route `/admin` which requires `Auth` middleware to be activated. I have the middleware requirement indicated in the `web.php` route. Also, I do have the default `auth` setup of laravel. 
The `kernel.php` does have the middleware indicated too.

But, weirdly enough `/admin` brings me to a white page with nothing. When logged in, the problem isn't there. It had been working and all of a sudden it was not working anymore.

The auth middleware is as it is:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\NewsletterSubscribers;
use App\User;
use File;

class adminController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->middleware('auth');    
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }

    public function index(){

        return view('admin.home');
    }

    public function changebg(){

        return view('admin.changebg');
    }

    public function changebgimage(Request $request){
     $this->validate($request,
    [
     'image'=>'required|image|mimes:jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG|max:4096|dimensions:max_width:1600,max_height:1100',
      ]
    );

        $path="images/";
        $imagepath="images/bg.jpg";
        if( File::exists($imagepath))
        {
        unlink($imagepath);
    }

  if ( ! File::exists($path) )
  {
  File::makeDirectory($path,0777,true);
  }
        $getimageName = "bg.jpg";
        $request->image->move(public_path($path), $getimageName);

        return view('admin.home');
    }

    public function newslettersubscriberslist(){

        $newslettersubscribers= NewsletterSubscribers::all();
        $count=0;
        return view('admin.subscriberslist',compact('newslettersubscribers','count'));

    }

    public function registerAdmin(){
        return view('auth.adminregister');
    }

    public function viewAdmins(){

        $admins= User::select('users.*')->where('role','=','admin')->get();
        //print_r($admins);
        $count=0;
        return view('admin.adminlist',compact('admins','count'));
    }

    public function viewUsers(){

        $users= User::select('users.*')->where('role','=','user')->get();
        //print_r($admins);
        $count=0;
        return view('admin.userlist',compact('users','count'));
    }    

}
```

The admin middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        else {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

The the route I'm using:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('adminhome')->middleware('auth');
```

I dont find anything weird here but weirdly enough the problem exists. Can you guys trace somethin unusual here or somewhere it can be??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have error reporting turned on.  Also take a look at laravel log. Looking at your code the problem might be case of `AdminController`. In routes you have `'AdminController@index'` but the class you showed has name `adminController` and it should be `AdminController`. I also don't know what is the name of file but it should be again `AdminController.php`

Comment: I got a little excited there when I saw the little 'a' . But, no it didn't matter when I capitalized. My other similar project is running good with that flaw though but still I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the middleware like this

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function()
{
  Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('adminhome');
}
```

Comment: The meaning of this and the way I'm using is the same. Still, I tried with this and no, nothing changed.

Comment: check the log in in laravel.log file